# I am using empty hair curve, and I am having an issue on why there's hair going through the mesh

Tags: uv, particles, eevee-render-engine

[image]
I am following a tutorial. Here is what the hair looks like before I enable interpolate hair. I wanted to see if I was doing it right, but I got this.

[image]
Excuse the low quality close up. The hair is going through the mesh. I tried taking away some of the hair strands but ended up with the same result.

[image]

Here are my settings. Under render properties, I enabled Strand and set to EVEE. It's not shown on this screenshot, but I chose the surface to be the 'hair base' mesh, which is the purple [part of the scalp shown in the above photo. I tried applying all transformations to the hair base mesh, but it just made the hair particles thick, and switching to Strip wasn't successful either, because interpolate hair didn't seem to affect it. It remained as if I didn't apply interpolate to the strands at all. The model is fully UV Unwrapped properly. Not sure how to fix this. Let me know if you guys need any further info. I followed a tutorial.

[image]

Comment: Have attached the hair to a hair cap or the head? If it's a hair cap you can try to split it into 2 parts (left & right). This might fix the issue.

Comment: It worked! Thank you!